# EAV default attribute value not taking effect

Tags: magento-1.8, category, attributes, eav

I'm trying to update an EAV attribute's default value, but the new default is not pulling through.

The attribute is

```
                'include_in_menu'    => array(
                    'type'                       => 'int',
                    'label'                      => 'Include in Navigation Menu',
                    'input'                      => 'select',
                    'source'                     => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
                    'default'                    => '1',
                    'sort_order'                 => 10,
                    'global'                     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'group'                      => 'General Information',
                ),
```

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup::getDefaultEntities()` ln 325

It was added in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.0.21-1.4.0.0.22.php, with the default value being '1'.

I need to set the default value to '0', and have created an update script:

```
<?php
/* @var $this Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

// set Include in Navigation Menu under Display Settings to default NO for new categories
$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_category', 'include_in_menu', 'default_value', '0');

$installer->endSetup();
```

This affects the new category form, when adding a new root or sub category, but the field still defaults to 'Yes'.

There has not been any other code added to affect that field, but when I debug, when the block gets created in `Mage_Core_Model_Layout::createBlock` it's returned the field is set to '1' and not '0' as expected.

Could anyone help me analyze this problem? I have checked the DB and the default value was updated by the update script, and when the attributes are loaded the default value of include_in_menu is '0'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*include_in_menu* is hardcoded to 1 for new categories in *app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php* 
*_prepareForm* around line 154:

```
    if (!$this->getCategory()->getId()){                                                                                                                                      
        $this->getCategory()->setIncludeInMenu(1);
    }
```

see https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php#L154

if you want *include_in_menu* to respect attribute's *default_value* just rewrite app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php *_prepareForm* and comment those lines.